# Using promisified data access in bogart

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to set up a simple blog with [bogartjs](https://github.com/nrstott/bogart) and couchdb.

I use the viewEngine like this:

```js
var viewEngine = bogart.viewEngine('mustache', path.join(bogart.maindir(), 'views'));
```

To get the list of all posts from the database I use `bogart.promisify` to do the actual call and return a promise, like this:

```js
router.get('/postsp', function(req) {
  var articles = nano.db.use('articles');

  var readlist = bogart.promisify(articles.list);

  readlist().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return viewEngine.respond('posts.html', data)
  });
  console.log('render');
});
```

But this method does not return the template `posts.html` with the data. This is in the console:

```
render
{ total_rows: 2,
  offset: 0,
  rows:
   [ { id: '1ec1ba2efd99b08a296022a471000adc',
       key: '1ec1ba2efd99b08a296022a471000adc',
       value: [Object] },
     { id: '20ce1f108a8bdf2f19f04f42b0001a04',
       key: '20ce1f108a8bdf2f19f04f42b0001a04',
       value: [Object] } ] }
```

How do I return/render the template with the outcome of the promise?

Answer (score 0):

The context is required to your object. This is for the same reason:

```
var log = console.log;
log(15); // exception in browsers.
```

Pass the context:

```
var readlist = bogart.promisify(articles.list, articles);
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the answer. The articles are fetched in the promisified nano-call. `console.log(data)` actually spits out all the data in the database. Only the response does not get rendered. As seen in the log, the console message 'render' gets printed before the aforementioned console message with the data. The problem here is that the `viewEngine.respond` never is executed, or that it does not do what I expect from it.

Comment: @tuvokki you're also missing a return before `readList()` - as in `return readList().then(...)`

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I believe the addition of the context does not change anything, but the return before the `readList().then(...)` did the trick.

Comment: @tuvokki promises and functions working with them work by return values. This is how they know to hook on completion and it's a fundamental part of getting promises :) Happy coding.